# Uncaught ReferenceError: driver is not defined while switching to Default Content through Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I am having trouble switching to default content. I use:

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

But am getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: driver is not defined
```

This is just JavaScript that I am using on a webpage.

Comment: Can you please share your code? It is impossible to guess what the problem is from this description.

Answer (score 2):

The error says it all :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: driver is not defined
```

This means when you are trying to do **`driver.switch_to_default_content()`** the reference to the **`Top Level Browsing Context`** is not available and error is shown.

Lets us assume we have a **`Web Page`** which contains 3 `iframe` (`nested iframes`) where one `iframe` contains another `iframe`. So the hierarchy is as follows :

```
page root (grandparent) -> iframe (parent) -> iframe (child)
```

Now, if we are within the **`iframe (child)`** and we have to move back to the **`page_root (grandparent)`**, we have to first switch back to **`iframe (parent)`** first then to **`page_root (grandparent)`** as follows :

```
//here within iframe (child)
driver.switchTo().frame("parent");
driver.switch_to_default_content();
```